# Library dependencies and execution order

Tags: javascript

If I have an object in the file core.js and I want to extend it in extension.js, how can I make sure that the object in core.js is actually loaded before extending it?
What is a good (and light) pattern for managing this kind of dependencies?

Comment: Loading core.js first in the HTML is a good bet, otherwise you can use some merging lib.

Comment: Can you rely on the loading order when you have multiple js in the <head>?

Comment: Yes, that's how the document is parsed.

Comment: As an important sidenote, this is why events like `window.onload` and the jQuery version `$(document).ready` exist. You should allow your code to execute only after everything has loaded. Checking for the existence of variables is cool, but doesn't help you much anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make sure you load your .js files in the correct order in the header of your HTML file. They will be loaded in the order you put them.

Or you could do something like:

```
if(MyFramework === undefined)
    alert('MyFramework not loaded');
```

Which will throw that alert error if an object called MyFramework is not currently loaded

Answer (score 0):

If it is an object then you should just be able to check to see if it is null  or undefined...

```
if (myObject === null || myObject === undefined) {
   alert("not loaded");
}
```

Comment: @Ghigo accept the answer that suited you so that users can find out the answer